# Deleting duplicate reference to remote Git repo (without deleting the repo)

Tags: git

I currently have 2 references to the same remote Github repo. Both references have the same remote URL, so when I do 
`git remote -v` I get:

```
myrepo  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (fetch)
myrepo  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (push)
origin  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (push)
```

I want to delete the `myrepo`  remote reference without deleting the remote repo. So I want to end up with the following when I do `git remote -v`:

```
origin  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<user ID>/myrepo (push)
```

I wasn't sure if `git remote remove myrepo` will delete the remote repo or just the reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git remote rm myrepo` is what you're looking for. It will not delete the remote repository but just your local reference to it.

Comment: I used: git remote remove myrepo